# How does the combination of flags in system call open() work?

Tags: c, posix

```
fd = open(pathname, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, mode);
```

My tuition tells me that this `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC` means the system call allows to write `and` create (if any) `and` truncate file (if any).

But isn't it `|` is one of the bitwise operator and means `OR`?

How does the system interpret the combination? I tried to use what I learn about bitwise operation to interpret this combination, but I just get lost. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Yes, you are adding bits in to the mask.  Reading the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open) may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitwise `OR` and flags are a bit unintuitive.

Say you have the following flags:

```
int FLAG_1 = 0x1; // in binary, 0001
int FLAG_2 = 0x2; // in binary, 0010
int FLAG_3 = 0x4; // in binary, 0100
```

When you use:

```
int flags = FLAG_1 | FLAG_3;
```

the value of `flags` in binary is `0101`. That means, the following flags have been set: `FLAG_1` AND `FLAG_3`.

Given the value of `flags`, you can check whether `FLAG_3` has been set by using bitwise `AND`.

```
if ( flags & FLAG_3 != 0 )
{
   // FLAG_3 has been set.
}
```

Same logic is used when you combine the flags as `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`.

More information on bitmasking can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing).